# Fast Enumeration With enumeratorAtPath?

Tags: objective-c

Are there any issues I may be missing using fastEnumeration with the enumerator below? I only ask as code examples (online & books) always seem to use a whileLoop. The code sniped works fine, just  curious if I am missing a potential issue. Please not this is just a test with no error checking.

```
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum;
NSString *eachPath;

dirEnum = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:sourceDir];
for(eachPath in dirEnum) NSLog(@"FILE: %@", eachPath);
```

gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples use a while loop because the fast enumeration syntax is a very recent addition to the language.  As long as the object following the `in` keyword conforms to the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol, your code is fine.

As a practical matter, since the default implementation in `NSEnumerator` just falls through to `-nextObject`, you're not likely to see a noticeable difference in speed either way.

Answer (score 0):

Although its often not mentioned you can use fast enumeration on any NSEnumerator object or subclass (NSDirectoryEnumerator) object.